# Using threading to find amicable number is taking more time than single thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am using to two function: i.find_divisor(): to find all the divisor of a number and ii. findAmicable number to find the amicable pair to a given limit in C++.
Below is the code for finding amicable pair:

```
void find_pair() {
    while (counter < limit) {
        int first_num = counter;
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> guard(myMutex);
            counter++;
            int sec_num = find_divisor(first_num);
            if (sec_num > first_num && first_num == find_divisor(sec_num)) {
                pairvector.push_back({ first_num,sec_num });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this function from main(). counter and pairvector are both global variable and i am printing pairs from main.For limit 100000, using 1 thread i am getting result within 596 milisecond while using 18 threads it took 1507 miliseconds. I am new to threading concept and lock. If I don't use lock i am getting some duplicated/or missing values and if i used lock the time taken by multithread is longer than single thread. Could anyone please help me how to get better performance with multithread. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do not use global variables, pass a parameter or couple to represent a range on which thread should work on.

Comment: I tried passing the limit while calling the thread. didn't find any improvement

Comment: You did that without eliminating globals and mutex lock? The you would not see any.

Answer (score 2):

You use `mutex` guard for all of your thread, what means that only one thread can pass over the lines in parallel:

```
counter++;
int sec_num = find_divisor(first_num);
if (sec_num > first_num && first_num == find_divisor(sec_num)) {
    pairvector.push_back({ first_num,sec_num });
}
```

And if another thread want to pass over them in the same time, it will wait until the first one will finish. Now, a thread have to get an order from the OS to start running, and your maximum threads that can run in parallel is limited to the cores number that your computer own. Now, if you have less cores then threads (or if the OS gave multiple threads to the same core) some of your threads will go to a waiting time until they will get the permission to run again from the OS.

Let's test a case:
OS: 8 cores.
The first thread get permission and get into the protected lines.
The second one start run and wait until the first thread will exit from the protected lines.
All the rest stuck in the situation of the second one, but now, there are some of them that are working on the same core as the first one. The OS will now send the first thread to a waiting time, and will let to one of the stuck threads permission to run. But, the first still stay in the protected lines, so no one can pass over them yet.
In this situation, all the threads are waiting to the first thread, and the first thread is waiting to permission from the OS. after some time, the OS let the first thread the permission and it exit from the protected lines- but, it took a longer time, because there was a waiting time..
**This case is an excessive case, and here only for a illustration**

#### How to fix?

Try to protect as less lines as you can, so there will be more parallel places in you threads.

Comment: I have 32 core system and i try to remove lock from some of the lines, the performance was better but i didn't get syncronized result. Some values are duplicating and some are missing so I used lock on whole code.

Comment: @user10470848 If all of your code has to be protected, there is no need of using threads (for performance). If you can't parallel a code, don't use parallel tools to performance issues :)

Comment: My response is just the explanation for the bad times in the threads way, relatively to the times without the threads- in case that the thread function is fully protected with `mutex`.

Comment: I got what you are trying to say. I need to change the way I have implemented the code. Thanks for the explanation :)